# How to check if the object was created within this month

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have a task to find out if an object is created within this month or not. I tried a lot to resolve this. I used `1.month`, `since(-1)`, etc. But still I am not on a right track to proceed with these solutions.

Comment: If you're using Rails, you should tag your question as such.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a built in way to tell the creation time of an object. You would have to explicitly record the creation time.

```
class TheClassYouWantToMakeObjects
  def initialize
    @creation_time = Time.now
    ...
  end
  def created_within_same_month?
    t = Time.now
    t.year == @creation_time.year and t.month == @creation_time.month
  end
end
```

Then, whenever you have `object` instance of `TheClassYouWantToMakeObjects`, you can check:

```
object.created_within_same_month?
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: 
When you do your request, you compare your creation date with `1.month.since(-1)` right?
If so, use instead `Time.now.beginning_of_month`. Time is a ruby class http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html

Could you write your request please?

Reedit: Great if it worked. My first explanation was not that explicit, thanks @Andrew.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But if possible can I know what exactly happening in this code? I mean to say, Is this checking exactly what i was expecting?

Comment: You should state explicitly what you assume the OP is using, and is thus required for your answer to work.